# How to run Google Chrome with NVIDIA card (Optimus)?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

How can I tell NVIDIA Optimus to always run Google Chrome on my NVIDIA (rather than Intel) card?

The "Run with graphics processor: NVIDIA" option doesn't seem to have any effect, and NVIDIA for some reason seems to disable it in the control panel:

[image]

Comment: You should now be able to take the steps you were initially taking. This no longer seems to be an issue, as of 4/19/2017.

Comment: @AP.: Sadly [this](https://superuser.com/q/990409/59271) happened. :(

Comment: The new Chromium based Edge will use the graphics card more readily than Chrome. I can't get any of these solutions to convince Chrome to run on my Nvidia Quadro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

It looks like a newer version of the GeForce driver allows the nvidia card to be
selected for chrome.exe

You can check GL_RENDERER at chrome://gpu which should then say GeForce.

===

According to NVIDIA, chrome and firefox both have been disabled from using the Nvidia GPU by design.

This is a death blow to WebGL in web browsers on optimus laptops and I have no idea why they decided to do this.

> "Radium3D said: I have an ASUS N53SV laptop which features GPU
> switching and I have an issue with 326.80 drivers not allowing Firefox
> or Chrome to use "high performance NVIDIA processor" anymore I only
> have the option for "integrated graphics" under manage 3D settings ->
> program settings. I did not have a problem before."
>
> This is by design. We disabled it for other browsers a while ago and
> forgot to do it to Firefox until recently.
>
> ManuelG

[source](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/573374/geforce-drivers/official-nvidia-326-80-beta-display-driver-feedback-thread-released-8-20-13-/post/3895121/#3895121) [geforce.com]

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/645918/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-nvidia-card-optimus/1207002#1207002).

Answer (score 25):

I figured out a workaround for this, if you create a hard-link to chrome.exe in the same directory, you can set a profile for that executable independently.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>mklink /H gpu-chrome.exe chrome.exe
Hardlink created for gpu-chrome.exe <<===>> chrome.exe
```

You'll need to run cmd.exe in administrator mode: right-click, run as admin.. and your Google Chrome application may be in another folder as %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\

Now I can run gpu-chrome.exe and have full 3D acceleration from my dedicated card.

Just right-click this new .exe and define a new predetermined GPU for running it as you did before nVidia blocked that option.

Comment: This works for me, thanks! Though I always have to edit the profile's launcher icon on the desktop to use that other .exe and also have to start with selecting nvidia gpu from the right click submenu.

Answer (score 5):

For recent versions Chrome (80 or so), head to `chrome://flags/#use-angle` and select **OpenGL** instead (the default option reads `Default` and varies by versions, where for Chrome 80 it's ANGLE), then you can right-click Chrome → **Run with graphics processor** → **High performance NVIDIA processor** to get your NVIDIA card running for WebGL etc. Check `chrome://gpu` to ensure.

At least for me (Driver 445.75, Pascal GPU with Intel Coffee Lake) Chrome never runs on my NVIDIA GPU when using ANGLE even if I set this in NVIDIA Control Panel. Chrome does, however, respect my selection for GPU (either via NCP or right-click context menu) when I choose OpenGL as renderer (as described in the above paragraph).

Comment: Cool, thanks! Also seems available on Chrome 78. I think you meant the default option is Direct3D 11, though. Also, I already have that option in the context menu, so I'm not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: @user541686 The default options reads "Default" and actually changes across versions. At least for Chrome 80 it's ANGLE. Regarding the context menu option, if you don't select a specific GPU to run on then it uses whatever determined in NVIDIA Control Panel.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this seems to now work correctly (at least when I posted this, May 2017).

In the nVidia control panel, you can select the nVidia card for chrome.exe. Then make sure to fully close chrome by going to the menu > Exit. And reopen it. If you check the GL_RENDERER in chrome://gpu it should say GeForce.

Comment: Not work for Chrome 80.0.

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows 10 (21H2) with NVIDIA driver 516.94 there is now message telling that NVIDIA Control Panel Manage 3D Settings is no longer managing the programs selection of the graphic processor:

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

So, you need to go to Windows graphics settings and add the program there and choose desired settings:

[image: Windows Graphics Settings]

Answer (score 1):

new nvidia drivers allow running with nvidia gpus, but you still have to run chrome with

```
--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds
```

parameters. otherwise backend always uses intel gpu. you can check this on

```
chrome://gpu
```

page and see for yourself.

**11/2017 update**

Nvidia Control panel on the latest driver allows nvidia gpu to be selected. If now, you can use NVidiaInspector(a third party software) to enforce it.

Comment: This doesn't seem true for me currently - qwertzguy holds true for me.