# Did my NVIDIA card permanently break by itself? Or can I fix it?

Tags: windows-8.1, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I believe this occurred after an Intel HD Graphics driver update, but I'm not sure.

However, I noticed a few days ago that my NVIDIA graphics card wasn't working. I tried doing everything I could: I uninstalled and reinstalled probably 10 different old and new drivers from different sources (NVIDIA, WHQL, Lenovo), tried the "clean install" option, etc. and none of them fixed the problem -- Device Manager simply says

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

and during installation and boot, the system freezes for 30 seconds to a minute or two.

I tried booting into another copy of Windows, and sure enough, same problem there, even though it used to be working fine. I even tried booting into Linux and then told the NVIDIA X Server control panel to use NVIDIA graphics, and it subsequently froze.

So basically, my GPU is permanently(?) broken as of this week, and I don't understand how. I was using my computer normally and hadn't done anything risky at all (no overclocking, no BIOS changes, no disassembly, etc.) so I'm confused what could have happened.

What could have possibly happened? And is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried powering off, removing and reseating the card and any connectors to it? It's a possibility that the issue is a mechanical fault coincidental with the update.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I've never removed any components from a laptop other than storage modules (RAM, HDD/SSD, optical drives)... is a graphics card easy to remove? I was imagining it would be soldered...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Seems like [I'm not the only one with this problem](http://answertohelp.com/nvidia-geforce-gt-750m-suddenly-stopped-working-in-y410p-lenovo).

Comment: Your post did not state it was a laptop, and when you mentioned a discrete "graphics card", I assumed it was a desktop. No, i would not advise the casual disassembly of a laptop, though you might check the service manual.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Oh I see. Hm so no ideas on how it might be fixed?

Comment: Try a different OS (fresh install, or 3rd part LiveCD); if they work OK (and report no problems) with your graphics card, then it's probably not a hardware issue.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 He already posted about using a different install, so we're talking HW.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, GPU is damaged.
It could happen either due to the overheating (especially in laptops). It happens very often. As for NVidia chips they degrade quite often when overheated, especially the old ones.

Degraded chips can't be permanently restored. Yes, you can improve its condition for some short time (max 3 month) by warming it up at 230 degrees during 3-5 minutes with hot air using Hot Air Soldering Station like Lukey 852D+.
If you do not have enough expertize in this, forget this idea.

Comment: I can tell you it definitely was not overheating, so that does not explain it.